# Filtering data in loop Smarty

Tags: php, preg-match, smarty

Is there any way to use preg_match or any other similar smarty function to do the following thing:

```
{foreach $resultsdata as $resultsData}
<div class="site_text">
{$resultsData.text|substr:0:500}
</div>
{/foreach}
```

I want to filter $resultsData.text and display only one part of this text.

Comment: which version of Smarty is used?

Comment: why not do it before you pass this data to smarty?

Comment: I don't see what preg_* is supposed to do here. If you simply want to truncate the string, give [{$string|truncate:500}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl) a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm asking because there's a [plugin](http://www.venturin.net/2012/01/17/smarty-v-3-preg_match-plugin/) you may use. But it's only for Smarty 3, as I see.

By the way, from your code it seems preg_replace would be a better solution, and it's already internal function - [regex_replace](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) - for it.

Comment: I used the plugin you've suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking idea of templates wrong.

Template should be used only to **display** data.
But data itself have to be prepared in the business logic part.

Otherwise there will be no good from templates at all.

Comment: This does not answer the question